Gather / Say Interrupts Slowly and Causes Confusion to the Caller
I have a dilemma that others have probably run into. Maybe there is an easy work-around.
This is the scenario:
I am using Twilio Voice with a webhook to my .NET application.

I have a Gather verb with nested Say verb.
The user interrupts the Say .. then pauses waiting for the speech to stop.
While the user has paused, the Gather thinks that the speeched has stopped and triggers the Action.
The user continues to speak but the speech is not being captured.

Current Solution: Increase the speechTimeout value to wait for the additional input.
The downside to this solution is that it takes a long time to continue when the user actually finishes speaking.
QUESTION: It there a way for the Say to be interrupted more quickly when there is speech from the user?
Has anyone else run in to this?  How did you deal with it?
